# granting database permissions in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a new mysql installation and am trying to create a separate user to have have access to their own database.

```
mysqladmin -u root -p create people
mysql> create user 'cgp'@'localhost' identified by 'myPass';
mysql> grant all on people to 'cgp'@'localhost' identified by 'myPass';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)       <-- problem here?
mysqladmin -v  -u root -p flush-privileges

mysql -h localhost -u cgp -p people
Enter password:
ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user 'cgp'@'localhost' to database 'people'

mysql -u root -p
mysql> show grants;

GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*xxx' WITH GRANT OPTION
GRANT PROXY ON ''@'' TO 'root'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION
```

As you can see there is nothing in the Grant table for the cgp user.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: try `grant all on people.* to 'cgp'@'localhost' identified by 'myPass';`

Comment: @tdi got it right.  Its not obvious but `show grants` will give out grants of the currently logged in user.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

`grant all on people.* to 'cgp'@'localhost' identified by 'myPass';`

- wildcard means that all tables in the people database should be granted access to.